# Configuring Qt for vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I tried to compile the Qt libraries so that I can use it in VS2010. When I run "configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2010", the command prompt says "perl not found--cannot run sycnqt".
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some dependency that requires Perl has slipped into the source distribution. See the comments here: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/12/15/qt-4-8-0-released/

One of the solutions given in that comment thread was to delete (or rename or move) all the synqt.* files in Qt's /bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the [Qt src tar](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0.zip) ball at (http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) doesn't require perl, the configure command works perfectly on msvc 2010

Answer (score 0):

you need to install perl on your computer, which is a requirement for syncqt. If perl is installed, make sure it is included in path